# How messenger works in sync with multiple devices

Tags: socket.io, chat

I am trying to introduce a messenger (chat) feature in my application.
I ma unable to figure out how to make the feature sync on multiple devices.

Let's say I am using the chat on my phone, and then I login to my desktop and start chatting there. How would I get the messages on both devices and how will both be in sync with each other. Additionally, for the sender to get a read confirmation, the message should be read from either one of the device, but the notification of unread should be shown on sender's device on which the message in unread unless he opens and reads it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: For future reference, if you ever feel the need to add tags for a front-end, back-end, database, communications method all to the same question, then it's "too broad" to ask as a question here. Work out which part of your application you want to start on, start it and then ask questions about that one part as you come across each issue. That's how you "can" use this site as a resource.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the guidance. Accepted and appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For First Part of the question you want to do Like FB Messenger where you loggin you will find your whole messages found not related to a device. To Achieve that you can have at the device app Last Login time which will be posted to the server, and all messages from that time will be retrieved to the user. But imagine the user has read all his messages from the mobile but he didnt open the computer since one Month. IF you didnt mark the message as read, he will find enourmous amount of messages coming as unread but he actually read on his mobile which will cause you huge usability issue.
For your Case I feel you need to do exaclty what FB Messenger does. Retrieve your latest messages from your conv with their actual status. And while scrolling up load by demand.

So Your Message will have only 1 Status(Read or UnRead) And date where you can match with Device Last Sync time.

Comment: Yes I got what you are trying to convey. Completely makes sense. :)

Comment: :) thanks.. so what your final idea of implementation ?  If my answer helped kindly mark it :)

Comment: The same strategy that you recomended. I have set a flag in db for delivered and read. When a user comes online, all the messages with delivered status false is fetched. In case he logs in from second device at same instant, he gets messages after **last message** saved in database. As the user scrolls up, he keeps on fetching messages from server. Please let me know if you suggest any more modifications in this.